# Manage Ember Multiple RSVP Promises on the same route

Tags: javascript, ember.js, promise, ember-cli, rsvp-promise

I am working with the GitHub API in order to load models in a specific route

I am doing two promises one for my personal github details : https://api.github.com/users/user and the other one for my GitHub repositories https://api.github.com/users/user/repos

I can load the models separately but the problem is that i don't figure on how to load both models at the same time in my specific route.

See the code

```
var IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(params) {
        var url, self, git;
        self = this;
        git = this.store.createRecord('git',{});
        url = 'https://api.github.com/users/user';
        return new Ember.RSVP.Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            return Ember.$.getJSON(url, function(data) {
                var item = [];
                git.setProperties({
                    name: data.name,
                    login: data.login,
                    location: data.location,
                    company: data.company,
                    followers: data.followers,
                    following: data.following
                });
                item.pushObject(git);
                return resolve(item);
            });
        });
    },
    model: function(params){
        var self, url, repoListProxy;
        self = this;
        url = 'https://api.github.com/users/user/repos';
        repoListProxy = Ember.ArrayProxy.create({
            content: []
        });
        return new Ember.RSVP.Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            return Ember.$.getJSON(url, function(repos) {
                if (repos.length) {
                    repos.toArray().forEach(function(item, index, arr){
                        var repo;
                        repo = self.createReposList(item, repoListProxy);
                    });
                    repos = repoListProxy.get('content');
                    return resolve(repos);
                }
            });
        });
    },
    createReposList: function(repo, arr){
        var record
        record = this.store.createRecord('repo',{}),
        record.setProperties({
            name: repo.name,
            description: repo.description
        })
        arr.pushObject(record);
        return record;
    },
});
```

How can i load these multiple models with Ember.RSVP.Promise in my specific route?

Comment: If you want one model to be the main model for the route, but want to wait for the other one to load before proceeding with the transition, consider using `afterModel` for the second one. Also, you are using the "promise constructor antipattern"; you can just return `$.getJSON` instead of wrapping it in a `Ember.RSVP.Promise` constructor.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since the code you posted is too long to read i didn't implement solution based on it. Here's a common example of loading mutliple promises within a single route in the model hook.

```
   model: function() {
        var store = self.get('store');
        var someRecord = store.createRecord('foo/bar', {});
        var somePromise = imported_promise(someRecord);

        return Ember.RSVP.hash({
            accessRights: somePromise,
            itemData: somePromise.then(function(resolved) {
                 // Do something here, promise is resolved. 
            })
            myRecord: someRecord,
        });
    },
```

Now if you need to access anything from route in the template or controller.

you would first reference to model and then the property.

*{{model.myRecord}}* or *this.get('model.myRecord')*

Since you're a nice guy for downvoting me i decided i'd write it for you.

I reccomend using Ic-AJAX : https://github.com/rwjblue/ember-cli-ic-ajax for async calls when you cant use store.find

```
model: function() {
        var store = this.get('store');


        var userUrl = 'https://api.github.com/users/user';
        var reposUrl = 'https://api.github.com/users/user/repos';

        var usersPromise = function() {
            return ic.ajax.request(userUrl).then(function(data) {
                return store.createRecord('git', {
                    name: data.name,
                    login: data.login,
                    location: data.location,
                    company: data.company,
                    followers: data.followers,
                    following: data.following
                })
            };
        };

        var repositoriesPromise = function() {
            return ic.ajax.request(reposUrl).then(function(repos) {
                return repos.map(function(repo) { // map returns new array no need to write container = [] . container.push(bla)
                    return store.createRecord('repos', {
                        name: repo.name,
                        description: repo.description
                    });
                })
            };
        }

        return Ember.RSVP.hash({
            users: usersPromise,
            repositories: repositoriesPromise
        });

    },
```

Since you're still using a different approach i went ahead and googled its syntax

```
   var gituserPromise = function() {
            return Ember.$.ajax(userUrl, {

    success: function(data) {
        return store.createRecord('git', {
                    name: data.name,
                    login: data.login,
                    location: data.location,
                    company: data.company,
                    followers: data.followers,
                    following: data.following
                })
    },
    error: function(reason) {
       reject(reason);
    }});
};

        return Ember.RSVP.hash({
            gitUser: gituserPromise()  
        });
```

In hbs i can now do `{{model.gitUser.name}}`

New link to it http://emberjs.jsbin.com/rutezi/2/edit?html,js,output

Comment: It's too generic, i can't really apply to my case

Comment: @Koala7 some additions.

Comment: thanks for explanation, it is much clearer, i just need to review the last part "return Ember.RSVP.hash"

Comment: not really, i am probably doing wrong in  the last part  "return Ember.RSVP.hash"  @kristjan

Comment: Try using "afterModel(model)" function in route and see what went wrong with your model :P

Comment: your answer almost works but the console problem is Uncaught Error: Assertion Failed: The value that #each loops over must be an Array. You passed {users: <ember-soundcloud@model:git::ember581:null>, repositories:<ember-soundcloud@model:repo::ember582:null>,<ember-soundcloud@model:repo::ember583:null etc

Comment: Hmm. did u use {{#each model as x]] ? You need ot use {{#each model.users as || user }} and {{#each model.repositories as repository}}

Comment: Not sure bout ember ajax syntax. But you can try adding empty arrays instead of promises and u can see it works. Currently the ajax requests are broken, Try IC ajax.

Comment: @Koala7 I Updated my answer for your promises, They need a little different syntax than we were using. See it for yourself.

Comment: @Koala7 add new link to http://emberjs.jsbin.com/rutezi/2/edit?html,js,output Also keep in mind the gitUser is not an array but an object.